# Scalatra livereload when changing static files such as *.js or *.css in the webapp dir

Tags: scala, sbt, jetty, scalatra, scalatra-sbt

So after running the command recommended in Scalatras guides, at root dir:

```
$ sbt
> ~;jetty:stop;jetty:start
```

I get jetty to reload changes when I make changes in scala files, but if I make changes in js or css I must end jetty and relaunch the same command.

Is there anyway to improve this workflow? how to **livereload** also when files inside `webapp` (`*.js`, `*.css` files) dir have been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalatra should reload resources under `webapp` directory by just start your apps with `set ~jetty:start`.

Comment: Thanks but it still only reloading when changing the *.scala files, not when I change stuff in webapp dir such as js or css files.

Comment: I make a small change in js or css, then save with intellij, and nothing seems to happen in the sbt prompt, am I missing something?

Comment: It looks to be occurred with only sbt 1.0. If you create your project by `sbt new scalatra/scalatra.g8`, try to specify sbt 0.13.15 when creating a project. or also you can switch to sbt 0.13.15 by updating `project/build.properties` by hand. Note that if you've once compiled or run with sbt 1.0, it might need to delete some directories such as `/target`, `project/target` and `project/project` after switching to sbt 0.13.15.

Comment: It was a problem in xsbt-web-plugin 4.0.0 with sbt 1.0.0. I reported and already fixed (https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/issues/355). So sbt-scalatra plugin will be also fixed soon!